# jQuery UI Sortable - how to include/exclude multiple "items"?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, items

I have a working example of the jQuery UI Sortable function. I'm applying it to a HTML table to drag and drop and sort table rows. It works great except I want to exclude certain classes of row from being sortable. Using the `items` parameter, I can successfully exclude ONE class (the `"list-button-bar"` class), but I can't for the life of me figure out the syntax for how to exclude more than one class. For example, I want to exclude `<th>` and other classes of `<tr>`.

This is probably one of those ones that is in the documentation but I'm not familiar enough yet with jQuery UI to know even what to search for.

Here's the working code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#applications_list tbody.list-tbody").sortable({
        items: "tr:not(.list-button-bar)",
        cursor: 'crosshair'
      });
      $("#applications_list tbody.list-tbody").disableSelection();

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried using a comma? The `items` option takes a jQuery selector:

```
  $("#applications_list tbody.list-tbody").sortable({
    items: "tr:not(.list-button-bar), :not(th)", // Excludes <tr>s without a class and <th>s
    cursor: 'crosshair'
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. "jQuery selector" - that was the magic keyword I needed! Once I knew what I was looking for it was easy to find. This doc explains it pretty well (actually it explains it much better than the newer version of the same doc, which is totally unfriendly to a newbie) http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors

In the end, I discovered it was easier just to include the <tr>'s I wanted using items: "tr:.even, .odd",
One thing that completely was the unfortunate coincidence that my form has classes called "even" and "odd", which are selector keywords. Adding the dot in front solved that.

Comment: @Brian: Ah, ok. Well I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

To exclude multiple classes of tr use:

```
$("#applications_list tbody.list-tbody").sortable({
        items: "tr:not(.list-button-bar,.other-class1,.other-class2)",
        cursor: 'crosshair'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Jquery UI 1.8 use the following:

```
$("#applications_list tbody.list-tbody").sortable({
    // Excludes <tr>s without a class and <th>s
    filter: "tr:not(.list-button-bar), :not(th)"
});
```